# descargar archivo de una carpeta, seleccionando una fecha en un calendario

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-datepicker

Buen Dia, estoy algo atorado con este ejercicio,la idea es, que basados en el calendario que se realizo (pondre el codigo mas abajo), que ahora desde una carpeta almacenada en el localhost con varios archivos pdf creados en distitas fechas,estos mismos puedan ser descargados o vistos dependiendo la fecha seleccionada en el calendario,si alguien puede darme una idea de como hacerlo de los agradeceria.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
        closeText: 'Cerrar',
        prevText: '&#x3c;Ant',
        nextText: 'Sig&#x3e;',
        currentText: 'Hoy',
        monthNames: ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio',
        'Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun',
        'Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Lunes','Martes','Mi&eacute;rcoles','Jueves','Viernes','S&aacute;bado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mi&eacute;','Juv','Vie','S&aacute;b'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','S&aacute;'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''};
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
});    

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Que tal @Geolo!  Lo que te podría recomendar es que cuando almacenes los archivos, guardes en una BD la fecha en que los creaste, dependiendo de esto, mediante el datapicker, enviar una petición GET al servidor con las fechas (rangos) de lo que deseas dependiendo a tu registro en la BD.

Comment: si, eso si me salio, pero lo que ensi se aferro el prof fue no usar base de datos, sino llamar el archivo desde carpeta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes recorrer el directorio donde tienes los archivos y obtener la fecha de creación. Te puedes crear un array con la siguiente estructura directamente:

`$ficheros = [ 
        "2018-10-02" => "/url/al/archivo1.pdf",
        "2018-10-01" => "/url/al/archivo2.pdf",
        ....
        ];`

Así cuando el usuario seleccione una fecha simplemente tienes que ir comparando fechas. Cuando coincida una fecha ya tienes directamente la url del archivo. Puedes tener más información [sobre la instrucción "filectime"](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filectime.php). Seguramente te vaya bien en este caso.